# Adding new item to an array of a reactive object replaces all items in the array. Why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

The main problem is in the title. My guess would be that the ref() and reactive() are somehow messing with each other, I just don't know how and what I could do about it.

The component using the store:

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from "vue";
    import { store } from "@/store.js";

    const game = ref({
        date: null,
        location: null,
        length: null,
    });
</script>

<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="store.addGame(game)">
        <input v-model="game.date" type="date" required />
        <input v-model="game.location" type="text" placeholder="Location" required />
        <input v-model="game.length" type="number" placeholder="Length (in minutes)" required />
        <button class="button" type="submit">Submit ✔</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

The problem occurs in the store, in the games array, after I add a second or more items...

store.js:

```
import { reactive } from "vue";

export const store = reactive({
    games: [],

    addGame(game) {
        this.games.push(game);
        console.log(this.games);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "replace"? Plz show more details about this.

Comment: I added different values for the second submit, and copied both console.log outputs. It changed the previous 'game' in 'games' as well:

`
Proxy {0: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(1)
0: {date: '2022-07-31', location: '99999', length: 99999}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false

Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(2)
0: {date: '2022-07-31', location: '99999', length: 99999}
1: {date: '2022-07-31', location: '99999', length: 99999}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because all the objects that you push inside `games` share the same reference. To fix this, do this change in `store.js`

```
import { reactive } from "vue";

export const store = reactive({
    games: [],

    addGame(game) {
        this.games.push({...game}); // line changed
        console.log(this.games);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is it, I get it now. And it's working too. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's not "replace", all the `game` reference to the same reactive variable defined in `const game = ref()`.

Whenever you call `store.addGame(game)`, you added the **same** `game` to the store. Because the `game` is reactive, is will automatic implement the latest input value by `v-model`.

If you put another button to check the value in store. Change the input value, and then click Test button, you can see the `store.games` changes too.

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="store.addGame(game)">
        <input v-model="game.date" type="date" required />
        <input v-model="game.location" type="text" placeholder="Location" required />
        <input v-model="game.length" type="number" placeholder="Length (in minutes)" required />
        <button class="button" type="submit">Submit ✔</button>
    </form>
    <button @click="console.log(store.games)">Test</button>
</template>
```